# Make Ctrl+Alt act like AltGr on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, pop-os

I'm trying to find how I can make Ctrl+Alt work like an alternative to using the AltGr button on Linux, like it does in Windows. I'm currently on Pop! OS 21.04 but almost every distro of Linux that I've tried over the years has also been missing this functionality. I found some old blog posts about using XKB but they quite far from complete and I didn't manage to get that working, although that might be a possible way to do it.

I would like to be able to do it natively without adding a program for it but as a last resort, that would also be a possibility.

Comment: Similar on U&L SE: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84707/108618) and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312772/108618).

Comment: Yeah, I've read those already, but none of the solutions there work natively, and the XKB solution didn't work for me. I've switched over to Linux completely at home for my computers, but I still have Windows computers in my household and need to use them at work, and while the Windows way might not be the best, I don't want to retrain 20+ years of muscle memory. 

I'd rather not have to use 20 shortcuts since, while it would technically solve the issue, it's just a workaround and doesn't actually achieve what I want, which is for Ctrl+Alt act as AltGr for all purposes.